# Keep JDBC references outside web.xml to deploy in Jetty, like in tomcat

Tags: mysql, web-services, tomcat, jdbc, jetty

I try to move some services from my Tomcat Server to Jetty, just to make some comparisons. Obviously I don't want to change my services, but I experiment some issues to deploy them with JDBC.

My services all use the same database to access datas, so I wrote my own library to make my requests. The services don't have any informations about the database, they just know they have to use the library. In this library I make connections with the database using this kind of code:

```
InitialContext ictx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) ictx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mysql");
```

In Tomcat my services work well just adding a line in context.xml:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/mysql" username="login" password="password" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql" />
```

So I just want to do the same in Jetty. I added the following block in my jetty.xml:

```
<New id="mysql" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/mysql</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql</Set>
            <Set name="username">login</Set>
            <Set name="password">password</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

The server starts well and seem to work, but I get an error when I try to access to my services. In jetty's manual I found it's explictly written that I have to add some informations in web.xml like:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DSTest</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

So I wonder if there is any other solution, than write the same lines in all my web.xml services' files? Like adding a common xml file for all my server with the same informations ?

Comment: Jetty 7.5 : jetty-7.5.0.v20110725 July 25th 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to the webdefault.xml that is used as the foundation for processing web.xml.

This file is typically located in etc/webdefault.xml of the distribution.

cheers

Comment: Thanks it's just what I wanted :)